# Set of Functions is a Vector Space problem

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, functions, vector-spaces, field-theory

Let $F$ be a ﬁeld.
Consider the $F$-vector space $F(X, F)$ of all functions from $X = \{ 1, 2 \} \to F$. Deﬁne
$e_1, e_2 \in F(X, F)$ by $e_1 = \{ (1, 1),(2, 0) \}$ and $e_2 = \{ (1, 0),(2, 1) \}$. Let $f \in F(X, F)$, and
set $r_1 = f(1)$ and $r_2 = f(2)$, so $r_1, r2 \in F$. What is $r_1e_1 + r_2e_2$? Explain.

-->so far, my attempts:

$e_1 = { (1, f(1)),(2, f(2)) }$
$e_2 = { (1, f(1)),(2, f(2)) }$

-or-

$r_1e_1 + r_2e_2$ = ($r_1 + r_2$)$(e_1+e_2)$ = (f(1)+f(2))$(e_1+e_2)$

but I am really lost on this question. Please help me, any hints are very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $f=r_1e_1+r_2e_2$. To see this, if we let $F^n$ be the $F$-vector space of the $n$-tuples of members of $F$, then there's a natural isomorphism between the set of functions $\{f: f:\{1,\ldots, n\}\to F\}$ and the set $F^n$ (and actually, some authors define $F^n$ to be this set. I make a reference to Lynn H. Loomis *Advanced Calculus*). Hence, in this case, you're just taking the basis $\{(1,0),(0,1\}$ of $F^2$ and expressing $f$ in its "natural coordinates.

There's another approach: note that every function $f:A\to B$ is determined by its domain, it's codomain and the values that it assign to the points in the domain. Now, note that if $e_1$ and $e_2$ are as above, we have that
$$
r_1e_1(1)+r_2e_2(1)= r_1\cdot 1+r_2\cdot 0= r_1=f(1)\\
r_1e_1(2)+r_2e_2(2)= r_1\cdot 0+r_2\cdot 1= r_2=f(2)\
$$
Hence, the functions $r_1e_1+r_2e_2$ and $f$ are the same because they have the same domain, the same codomain and assign the same values.

And I have to point out that it is not true in general that $r_1e_1+r_2e_2=(r_1+r_2)(e_1+e_2)$.